# Они должны были делить друг с другом свою участь при том, что участи их были совершенно различными

Tags: синтаксис

*Они должны были делить друг с другом свою участь при том*, ***что участи их были совершенно различными.***

Какой здесь тип придаточного предложения? 
К сожалению, своих предположений нет.

Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Это придаточное уступительное. Союз ***при том что*** употребляется при присоединении придаточной части сложноподчиненного предложения, в которой выражается несоответствие действию главной части; ***несмотря на то что, независимо от того что, при всём том что.***

Answer (score 2):

> *Они должны были делить друг с другом свою участь при том, **что участи их были совершенно различными.***

Если бы запятая стояла **перед** союзом ***при том что***, придаточное  ***"при том что участи их были совершенно различными"*** рассматривалось бы как *придаточное уступительное.* И, кстати, в этом случае возможно было бы слитное написание «[***притом что***](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE&all=x)».

В нашем же случае имеет место расчленение союза. Перемещение указательного элемента в главное предложение меняет тип придаточного, но на какой?

В виде предположения: *приместоименное изъяснительное.*

===============================================

> Союз ПРИТОМ со слитным написанием используется только в
>   присоединительных предложениях.

ДЛЯ СПРАВКИ:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Они должны были делить друг с другом свою участь при том, что участи их были совершенно различными.

Между предложениями в составе СПП выражены **уступительно-сопоставительные** отношения, или "несобственно-уступительные". Это означает, что противоречивость ситуации, характерная для уступительных отношений, ослаблена, а на первый план выходит сопоставление.

Примечание

Союз **ПРИТОМ** со слитным написанием используется только в **присоединительных** предложениях.

Comment: Вера, а по-моему, здесь явно уступительные отношения. И нет никаких сопоставительных? Что здесь сопоставляется? Что касается союза, то этот вопрос спорный: Валгина говорит: Союзы притом и причем пишутся слитно, их надо отличать от сочетаний предлога с местоимениями при том и при чем. Союзы имеют присоединительное значение, синонимичны и легко заменяют друг друга; имеют синонимы да и, вместе с тем, к тому же.

Comment: На грамоте.ру написано: Синтаксические конструкции, начинающиеся с союза «при том что», выделяются знаками препинания (запятыми). В «Русском орфографическом словаре» РАН рекомендуется написание «притом что» (слитное). Основываясь на этом, справка рекомендует раздельное написание, так и слитное. И ни о каких присоединительных конструкциях она говорит. См.ответы: № 204149, № 205706, № 207348, № 207455, 214667, № 215217, 215649, № 223942

Comment: ... я сеичас перефразирую предложение на "Они должны были делить друг с другом свою участь ХОТЯ / НЕСМОТРЯ НА ТОТ ФАКТ ЧТО участи их были совершенно различными" и как будто смысл сохраняется, как мне кажется.... спасибо Вам всем! Вы даже не представляете, какую огромную помощь я от Вас всех на этих страницах получила!!! =)

Comment: В сложных союзах со значением уступки используется раздельное написание местоимений: несмотря на то что, вопреки тому что, при (всём) том что. Союз ПРИТОМ  (ПРИЧЕМ) со слитным написанием - это сочинительный союз с присоединительным значением. Не мешало бы их различать, а не считать одним  союзом. Особенно при расчленении слитная форма вызывает большие сомнения.

Comment: Сопоставление или уступка? Они должны были делить друг с другом свою участь, В ТО ВРЕМ КАК  участи их были совершенно различными. Эти ситуации не связаны между собой причинно-следственными отношениями, поэтому они, скорее, сопоставляются, чем противоречат друг другу.

Comment: Вера, я бы не сказал: действие совершается вопреки другому действию. Да и сам союз В ТО ВРЕМ КАК  может употребляться и в придаточном уступительном.